# Is there a source for historical GDP by sector composition in the 20th century?

Tags: reference-request, gdp, economic-history

I've been looking for historical data on GDP for various countries, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_regions_by_past_GDP_(PPP) has been helpful in this sense; however I'm interested in finding data on 20th century GDP but decomposed into sectors, principally agricultural and industrial. Would anyone know if the data is there somewhere?